# Wordpress, all pages with thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Can we get a list (or ID) of only those pages of a wordpress website for which we have set a Featured Image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will grab all pages with a featured image and store it in a variable.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' ) );
```

Comment: Bravo, That Helps (Y)